# Updating "Quantity" value from program to the database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

i have a problem here.

Here is my case:

I want to update the `Quantity` value from program based on the value given from program and minus it to the database. For example: i have `100` in `Quantity` in the database, once i run the program and update the `Quantity` to `50`, the `Quantity` in the database should be `50`.

Here is my problem:

**I already can update `Quantity` value from program to the database, but no matter what's the value that i gave to `Quantity` in the program, the `Quantity` value in the database always updating to 0.**

Here is the code:

```
private void UpdateQuantity()
        {
            int index = 0;
            int codeValue = 0;

            List<int> integers = new List<int>();

            foreach (var tb in textBoxCodeContainer)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out codeValue))
                {
                    integers.Add(codeValue);
                }
            }

            string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity]= " + newVal + " WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", ", integers) + ")";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            OleDbDataReader dReader;

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(dReader.Read())
            {
                if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
                {
                    newVal = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                index += 1;
            }

            if (newVal == 0)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sounds.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Update", "Error");
            }

            else
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Was Updated Successfully", "Success");
            }

            dReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

The `newVal` value keep appear `0`. Because the `newVal` keep 0, the program show this when i click "Update" button in the program:

```
if (newVal == 0)
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                    sounds.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Update", "Error");
                }
```

But when i check in the database, the `Quantity` value is changed to `0`, no matter what is the value that i was given in the program and the `newVal` keep `0`. So, i think the because of `newVal` is keep appear `0`, then the database recognized it and update it based on the `newVal`, and this code seems not working:

```
if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
                    {
                        newVal = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

Could you guys help me out? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT Code:**

```
private void UpdateQuantity()
    {
        int index = 0;
        int codeValue = 0;
        string command;

        List<int> integers = new List<int>();

        foreach (var tb in textBoxCodeContainer)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out codeValue))
            {
                integers.Add(codeValue);
            }
        }

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        OleDbDataReader dReader;

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn); // error: use of unassigned local variable, if i put "string command = '' ", the program will run, but the command not recognized by system, and the error will be: Command text was not set for the command object.

        conn.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dReader.Read())
        {
            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
            {
                newVal = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value;
                command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity]= " + newVal + " WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", ", integers) + ")";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            index += 1;
        }

        if (newVal == 0)
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sounds = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
            sounds.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Update", "Error");
        }

        else
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
            sound.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Was Updated Successfully", "Success");
        }

        dReader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

change the following like this in while loop,

```
      newVal = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()) - textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value;                
      string command = "UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity]= " + newVal + " WHERE [Code] IN(" + string.Join(", ", integers) + ")";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after your while loop , since the 'newVal' is `0` when it was used in query and was updated later on.

Comment: @Furqan: if i do that, it will be messed up, because the `cmd.executeReader();` is on top or before the `string command = ....` and if i put this `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);` at top before `string command = ....`, it gave an error: `Command text was not set for the command object.`

Please refer to the question **EDIT Code** sir, thanks

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra, I have updated the answer, and moved the query line just before the cmd execution, please check now.

Comment: @Furqan: i don't get you, if i follow exactly like you suggest to me in above, what would i do to this one: `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();`? because that is should be at before the `while loop`? if i filled that command with `command, conn`, and make a variable `string command;` at the top, it should be error, because the command not recognized by the system (since the full command is on below inside the while loop), and if i declare the variable `OleDbCommand cmd` at the top and the full command is inside while loop, the `cmd` in `cmd.ExecuteReader` not recognized. Sorry for arguing

Comment: Sir @Furqan, please refer to the question **EDIT Code** again, i have updated my code in there. Thank you so much and sorry for arguing.

Comment: @FuhansPujiSaputra, is it still updating 0?

Comment: @Furqan: i mean, the updated code that you just gave me, it is not going to work, because of the comment that i was gave to you in the above. So, in other words, the program will not run, because there is an error, and i won't know if the value is still 0 or not since the program not running. Thank you so much